# Base64 calculation for extended ascii?

Tags: algorithm, encoding, character-encoding, base64

As far as I know - base 64 can represent *any* char. ( inclduing binary)

> Base64 encoding schemes are commonly used when there is a need to
>   encode binary(!) data that need to be stored and transferred over
>   media that are designed to deal with textual data

So I tried to apply it on extended ascii char ( beyond the 127)

the char :

[image]

after following the simple [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples)  :

I got to :

[image]

so the value should be `Fy`

So why when I use [online-encoder](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/Base64Encode/Default.aspx) and put the value by <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>178</kbd> ,

[image]

I get  this result :

[image]

What is going on here ?

Comment: I would guess the character is being encoded in UTF8 first, which will produce two bytes before base-64 encoding starts.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yeah  , thanks I wrote the result if you want to see...

Comment: base 64 can represent any _byte_. Your confusion is in getting from a char to byte(s) before the Base64.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Hi. the thing which I dont understand  :  byte can represent any value from 0-255. and the 178 is between this interval. so he actually needs 1 byte. why still he represent him as 3 bytes ? just because .net chr is unicode ? even so - according to msdn : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sx7t66b(v=vs.100).aspx it says that it uses 2 bytes. so why vs shows me 3 bytes ?

Comment: In memory, all chars are Unicode and 16 bits. The fun starts when Text is streamed. You always need an Encoding. With ANSI it will be 1 byte, with UTF8 a char can be 1-3 bytes.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Because you're not entering bytes in the online form, you're entering characters. Specifically, the Character with unicode codepoint 178 - which your browser then encodes in some fashion, and the app behind the form then Base64 encodes.

Comment: By the way, welcome to the '90s and Unicode. We don't have "Extended ASCII" here.

Comment: @NickJohnson since i have quite large expereience in dos - i allowed myself to reference it with that term. Also  I know that today we use unicode - but thanks for the funny comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser sent the encoding website the UTF-8 encoding of the character. This encoding is not 178.

Answer (score 2):

That is the UTF-8 encoding of unicode character `U+2593`, which is the same as extended ASCII character 178.

[image: U+2593]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to  Damien_The_Unbeliever  && zmbq &&Markus Jarderot  :

[image]

so

[image]